# Google Play Services - Error=MissingRegistration when I POST header

Tags: android, curl, android-notifications, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I try to notify my android device, but an error is returned.

I'm using curl to POST data from my server to Google API.

```
<?php

$api_key = "AIza*******tdv2g";
$urlPost = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: key=$api_key","Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "registration_ids=APA9**o-LEuKN********dJa**Wjz4Juujv9FEiMJajt4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

// exécution de la session
curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Message returned on my browser : **"Error=MissingRegistration"**.

Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: have you added google-play-services..

Comment: Yes, and the registration_ids is the reg_id returned by my app.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem resolved !**

I found an other way, using curl too.
And now it's working !

```
$regId = "AP********4Juujv9*****MJajt4";

$registration_ids = array($regId);
$message = array(
    'hangMessage' => "bonjour !",
    'userId' => "12"
);

$result = sendNotification($registration_ids, $message);

function sendNotification($registration_ids, $message)
{

    $api_key = "AIzaS*****v2g";
    $urlPost = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";


    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'data' => $message
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
        'Content-Type:application/json',
    );

    //Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPost);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    //Execute psot
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result == false)
    {
        die('Curl failed: ' . Curl_error($ch));
    }

    //Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}

?>
```

Comment: I used this code, It's not having any error.. But didn't get notification